# how to assign an attribute of tkinter.scale with stringvar?

Tags: python, tkinter, scale

I want to make a Scale and assign it's "to" attribute with 0 and "from_" attribute with a stringvar like this.

```
import tkinter
str=tkinter.StringVar()
gui=tkinter.Tk()
s=tkinter.Scale(gui,from_="0",to=str)
str.set("50")
```

I also tried this:

```
import tkinter
str=tkinter.doubleVar()
gui=tkinter.Tk()
s=tkinter.Scale(gui,from_=0,to=str)
str.set(50)
```

I am stuck at this point

Comment: Every Tkinter widget option that can accept a Var will have `variable` in its name.  No such option exists for Scales, so you *cannot* use a Var here.  However, you can change options later: `s['to'] = 50` or `s.config(to=50)`, for example.

Comment: You mean there is no other way?

Comment: @uslj: Read [The Tkinter Scale Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scale.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want. The `from_` and `to` options require static values.

If you want to change the `to` value after creating the widget you will need to explicitly configure it (eg: `s.configure(to=str.get()`)